# Rails ERB variable not responding to CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

There is a <%= user.comment %> which is 3 sentences long comment. I am trying to display this comment in a 300px wide div. However, it is not responding to css. (i set the div to a max-width:300px;) The comment was display as a one long line of text, extending way beyond the div. Any suggestion?

Comment: define that rule in a css class and then wrap it around your user.comment line

Comment: I just tried this. Doesn't seem to work.
<span style="max-width:300px;">Comment: <%= user.comment  %></span>

Comment: I figured it out. style="white-space:normal;" did the trick.

Comment: Just so you know, a span is `display: inline` by default, so setting its size wont do much.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. `style="white-space:normal;"` did the trick.